# Remove character from behind using `Backspace` fireEvent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I try to remove a character from behind using the `Backspace` event but it didn't work as expected.

It won't let me delete the character from behind using the `Backspace.

```
input.focus()
const options = {
    key: 'Backspace',
    keyCode: 8,
    which: 8,
}
fireEvent.keyDown(input, options)
fireEvent.keyUp(input, options)
```

Reproduction: https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-library-delete-1-character-i4y3d?file=/src/input.test.js:507-753

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to solve this issue by adding this function.

```
function backspace(element) {
  let actuallyTyped = element.value;

  const backspaceKey = {
    key: 'Backspace',
    code: 8,
    inputType: 'deleteContentBackward',
  };

  const sharedEventConfig = {
    key: backspaceKey.key,
    charCode: backspaceKey.code,
    keyCode: backspaceKey.code,
    which: backspaceKey.code,
    modifier: backspaceKey.modifier,
  };
  const downEvent = fireEvent.keyDown(element, sharedEventConfig);

  if (downEvent) {
    actuallyTyped = actuallyTyped.slice(0, -1);

    fireEvent.input(element, {
      target: { value: actuallyTyped },
      inputType: backspaceKey.inputType,
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
    });
  }

  fireEvent.keyUp(element, sharedEventConfig);
}
```

And then calling it in my test task.

```
  // delete up 5 times
  let count = 5;
  do {
    backspace(input);
  } while (count--);
```